# Web Forms For Marketers Custom Class on Form's fields?

Tags: wffm

[image]
I am trying to add the custom class on the form field, can anyone help me that how can i add or what will the flow to add custom class for form's fields

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the link to the doc describing what you want to achieve:

https://doc.sitecore.net/web_forms_for_marketers/setting_up_web_forms/appearance/create_a_custom_css_style_in_a_web_form

And here is copy paste from that page with main points so no one tells that it's a link only answer ;)

To create a custom CSS style:

1. In the `Website\sitecore modules\Shell\Web Forms for Marketers\Themes\`folder, in the `custom.css` file, define a new CSS style.
2. In the Content Editor, navigate to the `sitecore/System/Modules/Web Forms for Marketers/Settings/Meta data/CSS Classes` folder, and in the right pane click `Extended List Item`.
3. In the Message dialog box, enter the name of the CSS style, for example Short Date. Click OK.
4. In the right pane, in the Value field, enter the name of the CSS style. Click Save.

Your custom CSS style is now added, and you can apply it to any form field in the Form Designer.